# modify source code hadoop

Tags: hadoop

How to  to modify the source code Of Hadoop via Eclipse and to compile a jar file with the code modified.And is it necessary to reinstall the cluster inorder to make the changes get effected in the cluster or just  we can replace the jar file created ??

Answer (score 0):

You can import the maven projects inside eclipse via import maven project of eclipse and then make changes. To build, if you have maven plugin for eclipse installed you can build it from eclipse else you can build from command line maven tool.

I think it should be ok to replace relevant jar, but again it depends. If ou have made changes like to Hdfs jar, and Hdfs is running then it will require a restart. But to be safe, restart is the safest option